# Optaplanner; What is the allowable size limit?

Tags: optaplanner

My problem has a problem size of 80000 but I stuck when I exceeds this limit,

Is there a limit for the problem size used in Optaplanner?

What is this limit?

I get a java heap exception when I exceed this limit (80000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some idea's to look into:

1) Give the JVM more memory: `-Xmx=2G`

2) Use a more efficient data structure. 80k instances will easy fit into a small memory. My bet is you have some sort of cross matrix between 2 collections. For example, a distance matrix for 20k VRP locations needs `(20k)² = 400m` integers (each of which at least 4 bytes), so it requires almost 2GB of RAM to keep in memory in its most efficient form (an array). **Use a profiler** such as JProfiler or VisualVM to find out which datastructures are taken such much memory.

3) Read the chapter about "planning clone". Sometimes splitting a Job up in a Job and JobAssignment can save memory because only the JobAssignment needs to be cloned, while in the other case everything that references Job needs to be planning cloned too.